# HR: margin-top won't work. Why?

Tags: html, css

I need to add a `margin-top` to my `hr` (can be seen in **Quem Somos** section). I've tried everything, but couldn't get it to work. I've tried adding `hr` inside a `div` and then applying `margin-top` to this `div`, but didn't work as well. I want to make the space above and below this `hr` equal.

Can you help me with that?

Live: http://baskra.com/teste/teste.html

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="quem-somos">
  <a id="quem"></a>

  <h1 class="quem-somos-title">QUEM SOMOS?</h1>
  <h1 class="quem-somos-subtitle">VOCÊ COM CERTEZA JÁ OUVIU FALAR DAS FAMOSAS FÓRMULAS DE BHASKARA.</h1>

  <div class="quem-somos-content-1">

A equação completa de segundo grau agora pode ter mais sentido do que nunca. Pelo menos foi assim para a gente. Aprendemos a enxergar resultados claros e perfeitamente desenhados em cada problemática que analisávamos, e assim encontramos o X.
<br />
<br />
Dizem por aí que números não se comunicam.<br />
 Já nós preferimos pensar que eles ajudam na evolução de qualquer negócio e podem se comunicar muito mais do que imaginamos, inclusive nos inspirando criativamente.
  </div>

  <div class="quem-somos-content-2">
  <img src="images/quemsomos1.png" />
  </div>

<hr>


<div class="quem-somos-content-3">
<img src="images/quemsomos3.png" />
</div>

<div class="quem-somos-content-4">
<br />
<br />
<img src="images/quemsomos2.png" />
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    hr {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 20px auto;
   height: 0;
   width: 50%;
   max-height: 0;
   font-size: 1px;
   line-height: 0;
   clear: both;
   border: none;
   border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Minimal jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: It is present in the markup with the margin applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your floats. Your elements are not aware of their true size even when you clear the float. Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="quem-somos">
        <a id="quem"></a>

        <h1 class="quem-somos-title">QUEM SOMOS?</h1>
        <h1 class="quem-somos-subtitle">VOCÊ COM CERTEZA JÁ OUVIU FALAR DAS FAMOSAS FÓRMULAS DE BHASKARA.</h1>

        <div class="quem-somos-content-wrapper">
            <div class="quem-somos-content-1">

                A equação completa de segundo grau agora pode ter mais sentido do que nunca. Pelo menos foi assim para a gente. Aprendemos a enxergar resultados claros e perfeitamente desenhados em cada problemática que analisávamos, e assim encontramos o X.
                <br />
                <br />
                Dizem por aí que números não se comunicam.<br />
                Já nós preferimos pensar que eles ajudam na evolução de qualquer negócio e podem se comunicar muito mais do que imaginamos, inclusive nos inspirando criativamente.
            </div>

            <div class="quem-somos-content-2">
                <img src="images/quemsomos1.png" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>


        <div class="quem-somos-content-3">
            <img src="images/quemsomos3.png" />
        </div>

        <div class="quem-somos-content-4">
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="images/quemsomos2.png" />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Then CSS:

```
quem-somos-content-wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now your margins should work on your `<hr />`

Comment: It worked perfectly. The trick was probably the overflow:hidden. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap your quem-somos-content-1 and quem-somos-content-2 with a container, put your hr tag outside that container. That should do the trick.

Comment: Just tried and it didn't work. Do I need to change something in my hr CSS?

Comment: try float left your hr